# excel: loop through column skipping values

Tags: vba, excel

Is there any way to skip a row inside a loop when it finds a certain value?

For example, I have a loop that runs through a column copying the date and pasting its value and adding one more day in another sheet using this code:

```
Sub Apoios()

Dim i As Long
Dim j As Long
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim ws2 As Worksheet
Dim ws3 As Worksheet

Set ws1 = Sheets("Plan3")
Set ws2 = Sheets("BASE_TOTAL")
Set ws3 = Sheets("APOIOS")

lastrow = ws2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lastrow
    For j = 1 To 11
        Select Case True
            Case IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(i, j)):
                ws3.Cells(i, j) = ""

            Case Not IsEmpty(ws2.Cells(i, j)):
                If ws1.Cells(4, 3) <= ws2.Cells(i, 8) And ws2.Cells(i, 5).Value <> "APOIO" Then
                    ws3.Cells(i, 1).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 1)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 2).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 2)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 3).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 3)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 4).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 4)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 5).Value = "APOIO"
                    ws3.Cells(i, 6).Value = "-"
                    ws3.Cells(i, 7).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 8).Value = "-------------"
                    ws3.Cells(i, 9).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 9)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 10).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 10)
                    ws3.Cells(i, 11).Value = ws2.Cells(i, 11)
                End If

        End Select
    Next j
Next i

End Sub
```

Although I have a Sub that runs through columns and write on cells "TECNICO NAO ENCONTRADO" if the person is not found in my database as you can see below.

[image]

As this value is not a date I get a:

> Run-time error 13: type mismatch

At this line:

```
ws3.Cells(i, 7).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value)
```

Is there any way to skip the cells that contain "TECNICO NAO ENCONTRADO" on it?

Comment: you use "on error goto line" to skip the loop, Can you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you mean to change this line

> ```
> ws3.Cells(i, 7).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value)
> ```

and similar one if you have some, into:

```
If IsDate(ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value) Then ws3.Cells(i, 7).Value = DateAdd("d", 1, ws2.Cells(i, 8).Value)
```

Comment: It works like a charm, I always forget about `IsDate()`, thank you.